# Address family not supported error in android native

Tags: android, sockets, native

I wanted to create a socket and bind it to an interfaces ip address so that packet goes through that interface only on android in native layer. But on bind() system call I get an error Address family not supported. However I think I have given address family as AF_INET.

```
local = (struct sockaddr_in *)malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in *));
memset(local,'\0',sizeof(sockaddr_in));
local->sin_family = AF_INET;

optval2 = "wlan0";
memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(struct ifreq));
snprintf(ifr.ifr_name, sizeof(ifr.ifr_name), optval2);
if(ioctl(sock, SIOCGIFADDR, &ifr) == 0) {
    __android_log_print(3, DEBUG_TAG, "ioctl success");
}

ip = inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)&ifr.ifr_addr)->sin_addr);
local->sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);

local->sin_port = 0;
if(bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&local, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) < 0 ) {
    __android_log_print(3, DEBUG_TAG, "error %d string %s", errno, strerror(errno));
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 03-28 17:24:42.782: D/our_activity(5613): ioctl success
03-28 17:24:42.782: D/our_activity(5613): local ip addr 219.64.74.5
03-28 17:24:42.782: D/our_activity(5613): error 97 string Address family not supported by protocol
03-28 17:24:42.782: D/our_activity(5613): Need IP host www.google.com
03-28 17:24:43.157: D/our_activity(5613): IP is 173.194.38.146

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't this part of the `bind` call:

```
(struct sockaddr*)&local
```

be

```
(struct sockaddr*)local
```

since local already is a pointer?